# Problem deploying refreshly taken over project

Tags: java, maven

I am recieving the following error when I try to deploy my war to tomcat and I would be extremely greateful for whatever help can be provided. I have provided the error/stacktrace and the source code it appears to refer to. Any help that can be given to fix the source code would be appreciated muchly.

If you need more details please ask as SO viewed it as spam so I had to remove the more useful details.

What I really need help with is indeitfy6ing the problem with the code below to understand why tomcat rejects it but I am totally clueless as I only took over the code a few days ago.

I am sure there is someone that can understand this more than I can on StackOverflow. So hopefully you guys will help me.
Sorry for the spammy message it's because SO thinks my post is spam due to the large size of the log and the code.

```
022-09-07 15:47:17,779 WARN [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] [AbstractApplicationContext.java:487] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aggregatorGateWayManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManager com.textintegration.service.AggregatorGateWayManagerImpl.m_clickatelGateWayManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsGateWayManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2 com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManagerImpl.m_userDAOV2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOV2': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftService com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2.m_infusionSoftService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infusionSoftServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.StatisticService com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftServiceImpl.m_statisticService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statisticServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderService com.textintegration.service.StatisticServiceImpl.m_messageBuilderService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBuilderServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MobilePageService com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderServiceImpl.mobilePageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mobilePageServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.MobilePageServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userOauthServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.impl.UserOauthServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4763) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5232) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1775) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.82]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) [catalina.jar:8.5.82]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.82]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManager com.textintegration.service.AggregatorGateWayManagerImpl.m_clickatelGateWayManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsGateWayManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2 com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManagerImpl.m_userDAOV2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOV2': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftService com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2.m_infusionSoftService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infusionSoftServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.StatisticService com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftServiceImpl.m_statisticService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statisticServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderService com.textintegration.service.StatisticServiceImpl.m_messageBuilderService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBuilderServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MobilePageService com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderServiceImpl.mobilePageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mobilePageServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.MobilePageServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userOauthServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.impl.UserOauthServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smsGateWayManagerImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2 com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManagerImpl.m_userDAOV2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOV2': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftService com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2.m_infusionSoftService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infusionSoftServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.StatisticService com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftServiceImpl.m_statisticService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statisticServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderService com.textintegration.service.StatisticServiceImpl.m_messageBuilderService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBuilderServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MobilePageService com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderServiceImpl.mobilePageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mobilePageServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.MobilePageServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userOauthServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.impl.UserOauthServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Wed Sep 07 15:47:17 CEST 2022 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Wed Sep 07 15:47:17 CEST 2022 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2 com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManagerImpl.m_userDAOV2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOV2': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftService com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2.m_infusionSoftService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infusionSoftServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.StatisticService com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftServiceImpl.m_statisticService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statisticServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderService com.textintegration.service.StatisticServiceImpl.m_messageBuilderService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBuilderServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MobilePageService com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderServiceImpl.mobilePageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mobilePageServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.MobilePageServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userOauthServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.impl.UserOauthServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOV2': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftService com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2.m_infusionSoftService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infusionSoftServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.StatisticService com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftServiceImpl.m_statisticService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'statisticServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderService com.textintegration.service.StatisticServiceImpl.m_messageBuilderService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageBuilderServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MobilePageService com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderServiceImpl.mobilePageService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mobilePageServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.MobilePageServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userOauthServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService com.textintegration.service.impl.UserOauthServiceImpl.userOauthService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The above is only one of the errors ( the first ) I came across so I expect I will need more posts than this one to get the code accepted on tomcat manager.

I have recently taken over this code base so I am not aware of any problems it might have. I recently changed it from a gradle to maven project. Below is the file that gives the error:

Any help would be appreciated as I am not at all aware of the code and I am trying my best to get the WAR deployed ASAP so that I can start to view and debug the website.

Answer (score 0):

Several beans are missing during auto-configuration.
So, read below error (bottom to up) and register required beans.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'aggregatorGateWayManagerImpl': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManager
> com.textintegration.service.AggregatorGateWayManagerImpl.m_clickatelGateWayManager;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'smsGateWayManagerImpl': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2
> com.textintegration.service.SmsGateWayManagerImpl.m_userDAOV2; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'userDAOV2': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private
> com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftService
> com.textintegration.dao.UserDAOV2.m_infusionSoftService; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'infusionSoftServiceImpl': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.StatisticService
> com.textintegration.service.InfusionSoftServiceImpl.m_statisticService;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'statisticServiceImpl': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private
> com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderService
> com.textintegration.service.StatisticServiceImpl.m_messageBuilderService;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'messageBuilderServiceImpl': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.MobilePageService
> com.textintegration.service.MessageBuilderServiceImpl.mobilePageService;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'mobilePageServiceImpl': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService
> com.textintegration.service.MobilePageServiceImpl.userOauthService;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userOauthServiceImpl': Injection of autowired
> dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService
> com.textintegration.service.impl.UserOauthServiceImpl.userOauthService;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type [com.textintegration.service.UserOauthService]
> found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
> autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}